# Integrating vim into matlab

Tags: matlab, vim, editor, text-editor

Is it possible to integrate the `vim` text editor into `matlab` editor in order to take advantage of vim text editing and vim plugins?

Comment: Thank you! There is indeed one optional solution. I hope I can use vim inside the matlab editor.